# Cannot find function in knitr, even though I can see that it is loaded

Tags: r, knitr, devtools, roxygen

I'm trying to use a function from a toy package that I've put on GitHub (rblissett/pubpub) within knitr, and even though I can load the package just fine in the R console and run the functions, and even though I can force installation and see the HTML links being loaded, it still consistently gives me an error when I try to knit the document.

More specifics (the function I am trying is `graph_mcso()`):

(1) I can install the package just fine using `install_github()`, and after loading it with `library()`, I am able to use the function just fine in the console.

(2) When I knit the document, right now, I have the `force=T` option set on `install_github()` just so I can see the loading, and it indeed shows the `graph_mcso` HTML link.

Then when it hits the chunk where I actually try to use the function, it throws the `could not find function "graph_mcso"` error.

I've tried closing R and re-opening it, detaching and reloading the package, etc. I feel like I am missing something basic. The package was created and documented using `roxygen2`.

Comment: You need to `@export` the function to make it availble. To use any function from a package it needs to be exported (i.e., listed in the NAMESPACE), so that you can call it directly. Otherwise, you'll need to prefix the function with `:::` - e.g. `pubpub:::graph_mcso()`

Comment: Do you call `library()` within the document?

Comment: Ah, thanks @SymbolixAU! I was struggling with finding the language for what was going wrong, and that was it!